# Is there a way to limit a column's data to a list in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to create a drop-down combobox for a column, so that it easier for data entry. I know about using a form, but are there any other ways to do this in spreadsheet view?

For example, in Excel you can choose Data > Validation... > List. Then when you select a cell, you will see a drop down arrow on the right.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Brad Gardner, validation is possible with a drop-down showing acceptable values:

[image: WA434 example]

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, dropdowns in Google Spreadsheets are not yet supported.

Here is a link to a somewhat old groups discussion on it:

http://groups.google.com/group/How-to-Documents/browse_thread/thread/115eac535bcc1435

Its from 2008, but I don't believe the status on this has changed since then.

Comment: Just a quick update: Creating drop down menus for data validation is now supported in Google Spreadsheets.